# Как установить ovirt на один сервер centos 7?

Tags: centos, виртуализация

После установки ovirt на сервере 10.0.0.10
Захожу в административный интерфейс и добавляю хост 10.0.0.10
И все. Я больше не могу зайти в интерфейс.

Подскажите особенности установки ovirt на единственный сервер.

Comment: по умолчанию в centos порты 0-1023 закрыты. посмотрите и откройте

Answer (score 0):

Возможно после добавлении хоста, на нём активировался iptables. При добавлении хоста в кластер попробуй убрать чекбокс - Advanced parameters -> Automatically configure host firewall.